# Issues with correctly obtaining information from a QR scanner in Android device

Tags: android, react-native

Good day everyone. I'm developing an app in React Native for inventory control on a tablet for a client. Users will need to use a QR code scanner to scan codes and retrieve information from them. The scanner I'm using is a Zebra DS3678, and the tablet essentially recognizes the scanner as a physical keyboard. The problem I'm facing is that I need to scan codes containing strings like the following:

OPERATION;PART_NUMBER;SUPPLIER NAME;QUANTITY;SUPPLIER_LOT;INTERNAL_LOT;0;PO;RECEIVED_DATE;EMPLOYEE NAME;EXP_DATE;REV;BOX_NUMBER;TOTAL_NUMBER

and to input the code, it should be entered into a TextInput. However, when scanning the code, it's entered incorrectly, with some characters missing or misplaced.

Here's an example:

Code data: Receiving;PCBA0013;YZA CORP LTD;528;197015;TJM213004;0;307596;2023-10-23;JUAN VARGAS;2033-10-23;4;3;10

Data entered in the TextInput: ReceivedñPCBA0013ñYZA CORP LTDñ528ñ197015ñTJM3004ññ307596ñ2023'10'23ñJUAN VARGASñ2033'10'23ñ0ññ10ñ021

The scanner works fine because when connected to my PC, the information is entered correctly, and even in the tablet's note app, it's entered correctly. The problem seems to arise when inputting within a TextInput, as scanning the code in, for example, the search bar results in incorrect information being entered.

What I've noticed happening is that while the text is being entered, the cursor seems to occasionally move backward, leaving some characters in front while continuing to type behind them, thus altering the code's result. And this seems to happen when the text is reaching the end of the visible part of the TextInput.

Is there any way to solve this or to obtain the data without a TextInput element? I just need to get the string, separate its different parameters and store them in variables.

Comment: Please format your question.